Easy GN question - how do I get an extra geometry input to show up in the modifier?
I think I'm missing something obvious. If I add extra inputs to the Group Input of a geometry nodes setup, they appear in the modifier so I can set their values...unless it's an extra geometry input.  The attached screenshot shows a very simple example.  I'm using Blender 4.3.  Already tried googling but the answer appears to be ungooglable. Hope it's an easy one!


Easy answer: This is not possible directly. A GN modifier has exactly one input, namely the underlying geometry. If you want to include other objects, you do this via the Object Info node. You can use its input as input in your panel.

I guess I'm confused why is it even possible to add a extra geometry input to the Group Input then -- how would I route some geometry into this input?

@Threedio you can use a "group" of geometry nodes inside another geometry nodes (nesting), then the "Geometry" input can be used and will be visible, but again only inside the geometry nodes

Thanks!  I will use the approach quellenform suggested.
